# How to access to specify file in subfolder without change working directory In R?

Tags: r, csv

In R, I want to access to some file in subfolder. But I don't want to change working directory then move back.  It lost time and long.

For exmaple, I working on `/home/phuong` folder.
Here is the tree structure of phuong.

```
phuong-> data1, data2, data3.
data1-> abc.csv, def.csv, script1.R
data2-> bond.csv, option.csv, pricing.R
data3->.....
```

So i want to load data in abc.csv, def.csv and run code in pricing.R.

So if use code `setwd`, it make me lost many time and look code so stupid, like this:

```
setwd("/home/phuong/data1" );

read.csv("abc.csv");
read.csv("def.csv");
setwd("/home/phuong/data2" );
source("pricing.R")
```

I lost a lot of times to move from folder to another folder but all of them in the same folder `home/phuong/`. 
So I need some way to access to any file in subfolder without `setwd` command.
Please help me , thks.

Comment: Why do you need to change the directory every time? It's not necessary.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Assuming your working directory is `/home/hermie` and you want to load a `.csv` file from a directory below your current WD (let's say `/home/hermie/data`), you can simply do this:

```
setwd('/home/hermie')
myData <- read.csv('./data/myCsvFile.csv')
```

Of course you could also navigate "upwards" in the directory tree. Let's say you want to load a file in Bob's home directory (`/home/bob`). You can do it as follows:

```
setwd('/home/hermie')
data_from_bob <- read.csv('../bob/otherDataFile.csv') # Of course, this will work
                                                      # only if you can read
                                                      # files from that directory
```

Hope this helps.

---

***Update***

Somehow I think you want someone to write the solution for you... and I propose this:

```
> setwd('/home/phuong')
> data_abc <- read.csv('./data1/abc.csv')
> data_def <- read.csv('./data1/def.csv')
> source('./data2/pricing.R')
```

Is it really *so* dificult to write this? You would have to write much more if you changed your WD on every step of the way.

And, about my sugestion on symlinks, on your bash terminal you could do something like this:

```
$ cd /home/phuong
$ ln -s ./data1/abc.csv data1_abc.csv
$ ln -s ./data1/def.csv data1_def.csv
$ ln -s ./data2/pricing.R pricing.R
```

And then, from R:

```
> setwd('/home/phuong')
> data_abc <- read.csv('data_abc.csv')
> data_def <- read.csv('data_def.csv')
> source('pricing.R')
```

Comment: I know this way, but it make me type full path to folder, and when we load many files in some folder with different time, so it make my code is so long and complex.

Comment: create links in your file system. You don't have a problem with R, you have a problem with your folder structure... and that has two solutions: 1. reorganize your files in a way you feel comfortable, or 2. use links to your files (more info [here](http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-link-files-ln.html))

Comment: @Barrabka, i don't understand your idea, It the first question i ask about this problem.

Comment: what is so complex about writing the route to each data file you need? you don't need to change the WD every time to do that, and you will only write that once! Once again, if you want to have access to *all the required files* from a single location, create symlinks to them in your current WD, and simply read the symlinks (it's just like reading the file directly) (I am asuming you are working on a linux environment).

Answer (score 17):

You could use what Hadley calls a closure in [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) if I understand what you're after:

```
## Make a function that takes a path and another function
## and returns that same function with the path pre-progammed in
pathit <- function(FUN, path){
    function(file, ...){
        FUN(file=file.path(path, file), ...)
    }
}

## generate new functions that have the path pre-programmed in
read.csv2b <- pathit(read.csv, "home/phuong/data1")
source2 <- pathit(source, "home/phuong/data2")


read.csv2b("abc.csv")
read.csv2b("def.csv")
source2("pricing.R")
```

If you have a lot of stuff to read in this may be worthwhile otherwise why not supply the whole path to the actual functions?  If this isn't what you're after it was still a fun learning experience for me :-)

Comment: I prefer this solution more than the accepted answer. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

For me, the most intuitive way to learn to navigate folders is by using `list.files("../")`. You will see how upstream or downstream you need to navigate from your current location :)

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered the [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/here/vignettes/rmarkdown.html) package. I used it for a [project](https://github.com/davidmvermillion/EquationsofLove) I'm working on. It provides a cleaner method of referencing nested folders than the other options mentioned so far. As an example:

```
install.packages('here')
library('here')
here::i_am("pricing.R")
read.csv(here("data1/abc.csv"));
read.csv(here("data1/def.csv"));
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you were looking for, but I have a library of files in a specific github folder that I source when I initialize a project in a new branch, and I found one solution online like this:

```
setwd("~/repos/library/all_the_things")
library_files <- list.files()
sapply(library_files, source)
```

which is great except now I'm starting every file in a directory where I wouldn't want to save plots etc., so I realized all it needed was this:

```
library_files <- list.files("~/repos/library/all_the_things", full.name=T)
sapply(library_files, source)
```

and now it runs them without changing directories.