# How to reference files in R studio for local Shiny app development without changing working directory

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I'm pretty new to R, Rstudio and Shiny so I will do my best to describe my issue, what I'm trying to do, and why I am trying to do this.

I am trying to develop a shiny app locally in Rstudio before eventually pushing it into production on a remote server. I have my local file system located at let's say `/Users/kmyers/path/to/project` whereas I believe the remote project is located on a shiny server located at `/srv/shiny-server`. In my local project I have following files:

```
Project
├── Data
│   └── external
│       └── file.csv
├── other_script.R
├── server.R
└── ui.R
```

Now, what I want to do is develop my work in `other_script.R` and reference the CSV's in the `Data` directory. I eventually want to, I believe, `source` that script into the server/ui scripts so that I can use it.

My working directory currently seems to be `/Users/kmyers` and the closest advice I can find is [where people tell other people to just change their working directory in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357774/how-to-access-to-specify-file-in-subfolder-without-change-working-directory-in-r). But I don't think this is robust enough if I'm pushing it to the remote server afterwards, I would need to change that line each time I'm making a push so that it can adapt to the shiny-server and that doesn't seem like the best way to handle that.

I'm more fluent in python and I know that the way I would do this in python would be to reference the current directory that the script is in and just create a relative path based on that:

```
import os 
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Is there a way to do something like that in R?

P.S. I am not looking to develop in my own local `srv/shiny-server` as it seems overkill for development since I can just hit `Run-App` in Rstudio and it will bring up the locally developed webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shiny Server should run the app from the directory where the `server.R` and `ui.R` files are, so relative paths should just work. I think the advice to change your path locally makes sense.

Comment: Okay thanks, I had a feeling it would but haven't gone through all the steps of testing it yet because I was afraid it wouldn't work exactly. I'm not familiar with the structure of shiny-server, but is it correct to believe that it would still work even if there were multiple projects/apps within that `/srv/shiny-server` directory? What I mean is, its not like the working directory is `/srv/shiny-server` but instead it is `/srv/shiny-server/Project/` and therefore would still look for `Data/` within `/srv/shiny-server/Project/` and not within `/srv/shiny-server`

Comment: Yes, that's right, Shiny Server works great with many apps, exactly as you describe.